# selenium find_element not working as expected

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to scrape off a table from the tracking page of a logistics company. Here is my code:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#trackingNo").send_keys(tracking_id)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#trackingNo"), str(tracking_id)))
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#goBtn")
element.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.staleness_of(element)) # waiting for the page to reload

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"#SHIP{tracking_id} table"))) # waiting for the table to load
ths = [th.text for th in table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "th")]
tds = [td.text for td in table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td")]
src = table.get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Inspecting the page I can see that the table loads the data, however ths, tds only capture a subset of the rows in the table.

To investigate the problem, I'm capturing the raw HTML source of the table in the `src` variable, and if `status` (one of the th's present in the table) is not present I output the raw HTML itself.
Here is the code

```py
data = {th.lower().strip(): td for th, td in zip(ths, tds)}
if "status" not in data:
    print(data)
    print(src)
    return -1
```

And here is the output (retracting some personal information):

```html
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="track-details-bg track-details-bg bg-success text-right">Waybill
    No</th>
<td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th class="track-details-bg track-details-bg bg-success text-right">Pickup Date </th>
    <td>03 May 2023</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th class="track-details-bg track-details-bg bg-success text-right">From </th>
    <td>Mumbai</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th class="track-details-bg track-details-bg bg-success text-right">To </th>
    <td>Surat</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th class="track-details-bg bg-success text-right">Status </th>
    <td>Shipment Delivered 
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th class="track-details-bg bg-success text-right">Date of Delivery </th>
    <td>DD M YYYY</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th class="track-details-bg bg-success text-right">Time of Delivery </th>
    <td>HH:MM</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th class="track-details-bg bg-success text-right">Recipient </th>
    <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th class="track-details-bg bg-success text-right">Reference No </th>
    <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

As can be seen from this, selenium does load the table, but find_element cannot access th and td from this.

NOTE: At the moment I'm using BS4 to read in the page_source and parse my data. But I'm unsure why selenium is not able to find the elements. Thanks!

Comment: You do not *wait* for page to reload with `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.staleness_of(element)) `. That is syntax used to wait for en element to be clickable, or to appear, etc prior to defining its content etc. Please check [Selenium waits documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/).